# Diagonal in the power of a group

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $L$ be a simple group and $G=L^t$. The diagonal $D=\lbrace(x,x,\ldots,x), x\in L\rbrace$ is a subgroup of $L^t$. I can prove that if $D$ is maximal then $t$ is a prime.

If $t=mn$ then the subgroup $\lbrace (x_1,\ldots,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots,x_n), x_i\in L\rbrace$ properly contains the diagonal. Hence if $D$ is maximal then $t$ is a prime.

I can not prove the converse, namely if $D$ is a maximal subgroup of $L^p$ provided $p$ prime. For $p=2$ the statement holds.

**EDIT**

The problem that generated the previous question is the following: let $L$ be a simple group and $p$ be prime. The cyclic group with $p$ elements $\mathbb{Z}_p$ acts on $L^p$ by cycling the components, i.e.

$$a\cdot (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_p)=(x_p,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{p-1})$$
where $a$ is a generator of the cyclic group. We can then build the semidirect product $G=L^p\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ defined by the action above. The centralizer of $(1,1,\ldots,1,a)$ in $G$ is
$$C=\lbrace(x,\ldots,x,a^n), x\in L, n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace.$$

The question is: when is $C$ a maximal subgroup of $G$?

In particular, if the diagonal $D$ is maximal in $L^t$ then $C$ is maximal in $G$, but I am not sure that the converse hold (so the two questions are not equivalent).

Comment: Isn't $\{(x, y, y, \dots, y) : x, y \in L\}$ a larger proper subgroup for $t > 2$?

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the question to show a more general problem.

Comment: More generally, any equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{1,2,...,t\}$ induces a subgroup of $L^t$ consisting of the $t$-tuples $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_t)$ for which $i \sim j$ implies $x_i=x_j$. Are those subgroups induced from equivalence relations the only subgroups of $L^t$ containing the diagonal?

Comment: $D$ is maximal when $t=2$, and not maximal for any $t\neq 2$.

Comment: Do you want $L$ to be nonabelian? For $L=\mathbb{Z}_p$, $C$ is not maximal in $L^p\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for $p>2$, since $C$ has order $p^2$ but the group has order $p^{p+1}$.

Comment: Yes, $L$ is not abelian. For the first part of the question I agree with Arturo, but for the second one I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G = L^p \rtimes \mathbb Z_p$ (until the last paragraph it is actually not important that $p$ is prime). Suppose $\mathbb Z_p \le H \le G$. Then by the modular property of groups $$H = H \cap (L^p \mathbb Z_p) = (H \cap L^p) \mathbb Z_p.$$
Moreover $H \cap L^p$ is $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant. Conversely, for any $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant subgroup $S$ of $L^p$, the group $S \mathbb Z_p$ is a subgroup of $G$ satisfying $\mathbb Z_p \le S \le G$. Thus subgroups of $G$ containing $\mathbb Z_p$ are in natural bijection with $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant subgroups of $L^p$.

Now as you say the centralizer of $\mathbb Z_p$ is $C = D \mathbb Z_p$. To check that this is maximal it is sufficient to check that $D$ is a maximal among $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant proper subgroups of $L^p$.

Now suppose $D \le S \le L^p$. The (as guessed by Geoffrey Trang in the comments) one can show that there is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\{1, \dots, p\}$ so that
$$S = \{(x_1, \dots, x_p) : i \sim j \implies x_i = x_j\}.$$
To see this, let $\Delta \subseteq \{1, \dots, p\}$ be a minimal nonempty set containing the support of some element of $S$. Let $i, j \in \Delta$ and suppose $x \in S$ satisfies $x_i \ne x_j$. Then $S$ contains an element $g$ such that $g_i = 1$ and $g_j \ne 1$. Since $L$ is simple, this implies that, for every $y \in L$, there is an element $g \in S$ such that $g_i = 1$ and $g_j = y$. Choose $y$ to be an element not commuting with $x_j$. Then $[x,g]$ is a nontrivial element of $S$ supported on $\Delta \setminus \{i\}$, a contradiction. Therefore $x_i = x_j$ for all $x \in S$ and $i, j \in \Delta$. Moreover, a similar argument shows that $S$ contains every element $x \in L^p$ supported on $\Delta$ such that $x_i = x_j$ for all $i, j \in \Delta$. Applying this to every choice of $\Delta$ gives the result.

Finally suppose $D \le S \le L^p$ and $S$ is $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant. Then $S = \{(x_1, \dots, x_p) : i \sim j \implies x_i = x_j\}$ for some $\mathbb Z_p$-invariant equivalence relation $\sim$. The blocks of the equivalence relation must all have the same size. Since $p$ is prime, this implies that there is either $1$ block or $p$, i.e., $D = S$ or $D = L^p$.

More generally, essentially the same argument shows that the diagonal group $D \cong L$ is maximal in $L^n \rtimes H$ if and only if $L$ is nonabelian simple and $H \le S_n$ is primitive *or* $n=2$ (see Dixon and Mortimer, *Permutation Groups*, Theorem 4.5A).